# UIView animation slows down?

Tags: ios, animation

I am doing a basic UIView animation using block code. I am simply moving a UIImageView from one frame point to another. The problem is when the UIImageView is nearing the end of the animation, it slows down from it usual rate which I do not want. Is there any reason for this? How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` you can set what is known as the *animation curve* as one of the values in the options parameter. I believe by default it is set to ease in & out which is what you are seeing. Check out all of your options [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions).

Comment: +1 Probably `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` is what he's looking for.